# What are the differences between windows 10 PRO and Enterprise?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have 2 computers. One is running Windows 10 pro 1703 (creators update) and the other one has Windows 10 Enterprise (VLK). 
When I am comparing them, I see they offer the same exact features. Couldn't find any difference.
I have checked the list here:
https://www.howtogeek.com/271258/10-features-only-available-in-windows-10-enterprise-and-education/

I found all those "enterprise-only" features are available in my PRO version.

What's the difference between them?

Comment: LTSB is a version of Enterprise, not the version I have. Win2go works fine with Pro. App-V is available in my pro version.

Comment: While you have the "Create a Windows To Go", you will find, you won't actually be able to create it.  Even if you do, it won't be properly licensed, so it can't be taken to another machine.

Comment: I created it just fine. Yes, it is only licensed/activated on the machine I have my installation, but still - it does install and work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to [check](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10/whats-the-difference-between-windows-10-home-and/55338b22-d042-45cb-b9c9-a1be21b534e1) the answer in official MS forum. As i can see, the main difference are availability of LTSB version and different sets of updates for Pro and Enterprise editions. So, Enterprise edition [must](https://4sysops.com/wiki/group-policy-differences-between-windows-10-enterprise-and-windows-10-pro/) contain some additional applications and opportunities for corporate control.

> I found all those "enterprise-only" features are available in my PRO version.

[This](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/Compare) is official comparison from MS.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen all that. While those are the official lists, I don't see those differences in my Windows 10 PRO 1703. I have all of the "enterprise-only" features.

Comment: Do you really have BranchCache and DirectAccess features? Can you setup Credential Guard as shown [here](https://www.microsoft.com/itshowcase/Article/Content/831/Protecting-network-passwords-with-Windows-10-Credential-Guard)? Do you have AppLocker Policies in gpedit.msc? Can you manage Device Guard in your Pro Edition? Can you disable Win Store from policy editor? One more thing, in Windows 10 since 1607 some features (like isolated mode, if I remember it right) are integrated in all editions.

Comment: I think some of the features you mentioned are available only on the server editions. I can definitely disable the win store from my policy editor and I do see AppLocker policies in gpedit.msc

Comment: None of the people replying here actually have win10pro creators update installed??

Answer (score -2):

They are basically same, if you are a big enterprise owner and manage a big volume of pcs, some things like say your company computers are not allowed to do that and so on, with enterprise, there is an option with your big corp to give an usb to every employee and they boot off that, I can say, that normal users, don't see diffrence in enterprise, since the enterprise licence is bought by some tech group and they "illieagaly" put your pc to the fake company count, so you get windows cheaper, don't be scared, they can't manage your pc...

Comment: But windows to go works perfectly fine with win 10 pro...

Comment: from where were you able to get it to work? @CreativeMind

Comment: From my USB disk on key

Comment: If you mean works by you can plug the to go drive to a win 10 pro pc, then that is not the pro feature, that is a bootable usb drive, can be plugged in to any pc and bootable from any non bios password protected machines.

Comment: Correct. I installed it on my USB drive with YUMI and it works fine as my windows to go environment.

Comment: can we move this to a chat?

Comment: Yes, you are right that YUMI is not the official way. But my WIN10 Pro also have the "windows to go" option in the control panel, so I can use that.

Comment: Intresting, I haven't seen one on any w10pros

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xvGiXU1.png

Comment: I don't know about previous. My question is about the current version 1703 (creators update) and that's the one I have it on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61196/discussion-between-kristofer-vesi-and-creativemind).